# Detecting/tracking the motion of the hand for ASL letters "J" and "Z"

Tags: opencv

i'am making an ASL Hand Gesture Recognition program in using OpenCV for my thesis(i'm a novice programmer and new to openncv) and i'am wondering if how can i implement such a project, but the first thing i want to consider is detecting/tracking the motion of the hand for letters "J" and "Z",

can i ask what are the possible first thing to do in order to do this?? 
pls?

Comment: you'll probably get less downvotes, if you'd explain, that those 2 letters are not represented by a simple hand "pose" , but a gesture, i.e, movement instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by hand detection using V&J algorithm. You would have to train a new cascade using hand images.

Next you can track the hand (I would use simple bounding box update and prediction, but you can also try optical flow methods such as Lucas and Kanade).

Once you tracked the hand, you can feed the trajectory to a classifier.

This is just my opinion and point of view on the problem, It's hard to know all the stages in advance, but starting from detecting the hand is a good idea.

Comment: From wiki:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework

In OpenCV: